# JSF gets values from UIComponent

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I try to describe my problem:

Here is `page.xhtml`:

```
...
<rich:dataTable value="#{bean.myExampleList}" vat="element">
    <rich:column>
        <a4j:commandLink status="waitStatus" oncomplete="#{rich:component('editModalPanel')}.show();" 
                         render="editModalPanel">
        <h:graphicImage library="images" name="icons/edit.gif" style="border:0" />
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{element.id}"
                                      target="#{AdminBean.currentSelected}"/>
        </a4j:commandLink>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
...
```

Here is `modal.xhtml`:

```
...
    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{bean.name}"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.name}"/>
...
```

For example, when I click on the first row in the `page.xhtml`, my modal panel will open, when I submit my form and there are not validation issues everything is OK. But when there are validation issues and I close modalPanel, next click on the second row in the `page.xhtml`, texts in the `h:inputText` and `h:outputText` are differents. Text in the `h:outputText` equals to `#{bean.name}`, text in the `h:inputText` equals to name from the first row in the table. In this situation I think that `h:inputText` gets text from `UIComponent` from tree, not from `bean`.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to work like that when validation fails. To get the proper value you have to force a reset.

Use either `<f:resetValues render="id_to_reset">` or `<f:ajax resetValues="true" render="id_to_reset">`. In the next version of RichFaces (4.5.1), the resetValues attribute will be added to ajax components.

Comment: I used `resetValue()` method from `UIInput` class. It works ;)